# Laravel Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html

Tags: laravel, cross-origin-read-blocking

When trying to load images from external links, some images load while other not at random with error message in the console:

> (7) Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type text/html. See  for more details.

This phenomena seem to vary depending on my connection speed and time of day. All images come from the same origin and I can not find a way to prevent this from happening.

When opening the image url individually in a new tab the problem fades way for that particular link and I can not find any explanation as to why doing this solves the problem. Is there a work around to this problem in Laravel?

Comment: I had this issue when developing locally. Had to change to use HTTPS rather than HTTP.